# Zoo Visitor Update Hangs Browser But Submits Content

Tags: zoo-visitor

I have a Zoo Visitor form that populates a channel entry. All is well in that it actually submits the content. However, the strange thing is I would have no way of knowing that until I check ExpressionEngine's control panel and seeing that the edits have been made -- because the browser hangs the moment I press submit. It looks like it's perpetually loading. Then trying to go anywhere else on the site makes it super super slow.

When I close the browser and visit the form again, everything loads fast on the site. But when I make a change in the form and press enter, again, browser hangs forever even though it looks like it submitted in EE. It never goes to the /success/ page.

Help?

Comment: I also stripped the template & form down to its bare bones, just the update form and 3 text inputs, no styling. Still hangs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disabled MX Notify Control and everything began working again. It looks like that was the culprit!

Answer (score 4):

The most likely culprit is an extension using the entry_submission_end hook (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/) that is getting hung up.  (It'd be after the entry_submission_start/ready hooks, since it's saving the entry)

Your best bet is to disable all the extensions, and to see if the problem persists.

Comment: That would coincide with MX Notify Control (which she is using) too. I am curious to see which one it ends up being the problem.